# web2py : non identical field constraint

Tags: python, validation, web2py, data-access-layer

I would like to define the following table with a non identical field value as a follower should not follow himself :

```
db.define_table('followers', 
    Field('follower', 
          db.auth_user, 
          requires=(db.subscription.follower != db.subscription.user)),
    Field('user', 
          db.auth_user, 
          requires=(db.subscription.follower != db.subscription.user))
)
```

But I don't know how to implement it. Any hint ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming inserts will happen via form processing:

```
db.define_table('followers', 
    Field('follower', 'reference auth_user',
          requires=IS_IN_DB(db(db.auth_user.id != request.post_vars.user),
                            'auth_user.id', db.auth_user._format)),
    Field('user', 'reference auth_user'))
```

This will allow any `auth_user` ID in the `user` field, but will limit the `follower` field to IDs other than the one submitted in `request.post_vars.user`. When there is no form submission, `request.post_vars.user` will simply be `None`, which doesn't matter because the validator is used only upon form submission.

Alternatively, you can use an [`onvalidation`](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/07/forms-and-validators#onvalidation) callback function when processing the form.

Comment: I was looking for a database validator but your solution makes more sense as this is an user request feature. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Both fields still use the `IS_IN_DB` database validator (the validator for the `user` field is added by default given that it is a reference field). However, it is only necessary to limit one of the two to a subset of the `auth_user` records.